# How to search within a range of numbers in a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, montecarlo

I have a column on my worksheet that is supposed to be ranges of numbers like this (Random Digit Assignment).

[image]

Each cell are created by the ROW formula.

For Example

> (E4): =ROWS(D4:D4)*(D4*1000)&" - "&ROWS(D5:D5)*(D5*1000) (but it does not matter)

Now, what I want is to search numbers within those ranges in cells.
Like I want to search **210** and the result that I want is **5**

Is that possible? How?

Comment: So what if you search 200?

Comment: @JvdV what do you mean sir?

Comment: @JustPeter JvdV probably asks if input 200 should return 4 or 5, as both include 200.

Comment: oh sorry I used the wrong screenshot. I actually fixed it recently. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
=MATCH(210,--LEFT(E3:E18,FIND(" ",E3:E18)))
```

If you don't have ms365 and you don't want to CSE this formula use:

```
=MATCH(210,INDEX(--LEFT(E3:E18,FIND(" ",E3:E18)),))
```

Comment: OMG, the second one worked! Thank you so much sir! You save my day! Thank you!

Comment: The 1st  one would also work if you would CSE-enter it =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function in general for that purpose. If you had a separate column for start and end of range, then you could use two MATCH calls to find the closest start/end of range and then return the [address of the lookup result](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-address-of-lookup-result). You can compare the closest start and closest end with the searched term and choose the row of the one which is closer. From there on, the final step is to just get the proper cell in the row you found.

Comment: Im sorry sir but Im actually new to excel. I already tried vlookup and lookup but not MATCH. I tried but it returns N/A